# Why HashMap.get() return the last position under the same key in array?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int complement = target - nums[i];

        map.put(nums[i], i);

        if(map.containsKey(complement)) {
            return new int[] {map.get(complement), i};
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No solution");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[]{1, 9, 9, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoSum(array, 12)));
}
```

Why return **[2, 3]** instead of **[1, 3]**?

Does HashMap.get() always return the last value position under multiple same key in array?

Comment: your code is not fine, you are generating repeated keys, when you do put the second time the is replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashmaps work on hashing principle.

When you call *put(key, value)*, the *hashcode()* method of the provided *key* is called and accordingly a bucket is reserved in the memory for this hashcode holding the passed value.

If you called again put(key,value) with the same key, then the same hashcode will be generated and hence the hashing function of the map will access the same bucket and update it with the new value object.

So that's why, you should be careful when calling *put(key, value)* inside a loop in order to prevent this confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the **hashmap** implementation, **hashmap** will rewrite/update old value for a given key if it is present in the map, if not present will just *insert* it

you hashmap had this element

doing this

```
map.put(0, 55);
map.put(0, 88);
```

will *update* the value for the key **0**
 so if you try to get the value for 0 the hashmap implementation will return **88**